# yum search is OK, but yum install unable to match

Tags: yum

I published my app as a rpm package. And When I test it with `yum search PKG`, it's all right. But running `yum install -y PKG` failed with `Unable to match...`.

What I have tried:

`yum clean all && yum install -y PKG`, not work.

Have anyone encountered similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

`File permission` issue.

The pkg.rpm file permission is `0600`. The valid permission should be `0644`.

Record here, hope to be helpful.

Comment: if this solved your problem, the accept your own answer